# How to restart session once destroyed in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session

In one of my controller file I have destroyed customer session (Instance of `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`)and started it again due to some specific requirement.

```
public function execute()
{
    $customerId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId(); // 4
    $this->session->destroy();
    $this->session->start();
    $this->session->setCid($customerId);
    return $this->pageFactory->create();
}
```

And in another controller file I am trying to get session value as given below:

```
public function execute()
{
    $customerId =  $this->session->getCid();
    var_dump($customerId);exit;
}
```

which gives NULL. 
If I am not destroying customer session in first controller then I am able to get session value in second controller properly. What I am missing?

`$this->session->destroy();` is also deleting session variables set through PHP's $_SESSION. For example if I add `$_SESSION['cid'] = 4;` after `$this->session->destroy();`, I am not able to get it through  `echo $_SESSION['cid'];`

Comment: Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**=> Create session in your first controller :**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action {
    public $customerSession;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        ..................................
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ..................................
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Company Module Controller 1'));
        $this->customerSession->setMyValue('test value');
        $this->customerSession->destroy();
        $this->customerSession->start();
        $this->customerSession->setMyValue('regenerate test value');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
?>
```

**=> For Getting session value in your second controller :**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Save;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Save extends Action {

    public $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        ..................................
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ..................................
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Company Module Controller 2'));
        $this->customerSession->start(); // Refresh session before getting value
        var_dump($this->customerSession->getMyValue());
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Hope this answer will helpful for you.